# How to stop encoding url in template file on Beego?

Tags: templates, go, encoding, ampersand, beego

I'm in trouble dealing with template and url encoding on Beego.

(Beego is one of the template engines of Go lang)

How to stop encoding url in HTML TAG in template file on Beego?

Please let me know.

### --

logcontroller.go

```
package controllers

import (
    "mycode/models"
)

type FiletranslogController struct {
    baseController
}

func (this *FiletranslogController) Get() {
    // Already encoded url
    this.Data["querystring"] = "/filetranslog/getlogs?sdate=2016-11-13%2000%3A00&edate=2016-12-13%2023%3A59&md5=&trans_type=2"

    this.TplName = "log/filetrans.html"
}
```

filetrans.html

```
<!-- Not in TABLE TAG -->
{{str2html .querystring}}

<!-- In TABLE TAG -->
<table  id="table-log"
        data-url="{{str2html .querystring}}"
        data-toggle="table"
        data-toolbar="#toolbar-log"
        data-search="true"
        data-show-refresh="true"
        data-pagination="true"
        data-side-pagination="server"
        >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="rdate">Date</th>
        <th data-field="mail_sender">Mail Sender</th>
        <th data-field="trans_type">Trans Type</th>
        <th data-field="md5">MD5</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script>
```

view source on Web browser

```
<!-- Not in TABLE TAG -->
/filetranslog/getlogs?sdate=2016-11-13%2000%3A00&edate=2016-12-13%2023%3A59&md5=&trans_type=2

<!-- In TABLE TAG -->
<table  id="table-log"
        data-url="/filetranslog/getlogs?sdate=2016-11-13%2000%3A00&amp;edate=2016-12-13%2023%3A59&amp;md5=&amp;trans_type=2"
        data-toggle="table"
        data-toolbar="#toolbar-log"
        data-search="true"
        data-show-refresh="true"
        data-pagination="true"
        data-side-pagination="server"
        >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="rdate">Date</th>
        <th data-field="mail_sender">Mail Sender</th>
        <th data-field="trans_type">Trans Type</th>
        <th data-field="md5">MD5</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script>
```

OMG

```
/filetranslog/getlogs?sdate=2016-11-13%2000%3A00&edate=2016-12-13%2023%3A59&md5=&trans_type=2
---> changed to 
/filetranslog/getlogs?sdate=2016-11-13%2000%3A00&amp;edate=2016-12-13%2023%3A59&amp;md5=&amp;trans_type=2
```

*** ex) PHP Smarty template engine supports {literal} bla..bla..never encoded {/literal} tag. ***

Comment: Did you try using raw string for already encoded url (using back ticks)? Raw strings hold characters uninterpreted - https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals

Comment: I already tried  but it still. Thanks though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154937/how-to-stop-encoding-url-in-template-file-on-beego?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

- str2html
  Parse string to HTML, no escaping. {{str2html .Strhtml}}

https://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/template.md

Comment: It's honor to see you, AstaXie. I already tried. But, it works only outside of TAG.`{{.str2html .querystring}}` vs `<table data-url="{{.str2html .querystring}}"></table>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154937/how-to-stop-encoding-url-in-template-file-on-beego?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Second test result.

template_file.html

```
{{str2html .querystring}}
<table  data-url="{{.querystring}}"
        data-url='{{.querystring}}'
        data-url="{{str2html .querystring}}"
        data-url='{{str2html .querystring}}'
        >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="rdate">Date</th>
        <th data-field="mail_sender">Mail Sender</th>
        <th data-field="trans_type">Trans Type</th>
        <th data-field="md5">MD5</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

view source on Web Browser

```
/filetranslog/getlogs?sdate=2016-11-13%2000%3A00&edate=2016-12-13%2023%3A59&md5=&trans_type=2
<table  data-url="/filetranslog/getlogs?sdate=2016-11-13%2000%3A00&amp;edate=2016-12-13%2023%3A59&amp;md5=&amp;trans_type=2"
        data-url='/filetranslog/getlogs?sdate=2016-11-13%2000%3A00&amp;edate=2016-12-13%2023%3A59&amp;md5=&amp;trans_type=2'
        data-url="/filetranslog/getlogs?sdate=2016-11-13%2000%3A00&amp;edate=2016-12-13%2023%3A59&amp;md5=&amp;trans_type=2"
        data-url='/filetranslog/getlogs?sdate=2016-11-13%2000%3A00&amp;edate=2016-12-13%2023%3A59&amp;md5=&amp;trans_type=2'

        >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="rdate">Date</th>
        <th data-field="mail_sender">Mail Sender</th>
        <th data-field="trans_type">Trans Type</th>
        <th data-field="md5">MD5</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Why is literal string encoded? I use "beego.ParseForm" function for form parsing, however, double-encoded url is not parsed by "beego.ParseForm" properly.